# Sql Server stored procedure cursor name conflict

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I have a situation where one SQL Server stored procedure is calling another one and both happen to use cursors that have the same name. This is causing a conflict as apparently the cursors don't have visibility restricted to the stored procedure where they are declared.

Is there any way to make the cursors private to the procedure they were declared in?

Comment: why cant the cursor name be modified in any one of SP?

Comment: cursors are very powerful constructs and there are many things that can only be done in SQL using cursors.  yes they are slower than set operations, but so is pulling all your data out of the database, processing it and pushing it back in, which is what many people would happily do to avoid using a cursor when a cursor works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a local keyword.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/sqlserver/article.php/c7177

Comment: By default, if the LOCAL / GLOBAL switch isn't filled out when declaring the cursor, it will be implicitly set to LOCAL. I do however suggest that LOCAL be defined for other peoples clarity when reading your code.

Comment: Ben's comment is incorrect.  The default setting (LOCAL / GLOBAL) is controlled by the is_local_cursor_default setting in sys.databases.  See this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 7):

Use the LOCAL option when [declaring the cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

> **LOCAL**
>
> Specifies that the scope of the cursor
>   is local to the batch, stored
>   procedure, or trigger in which the
>   cursor was created. The cursor name is
>   only valid within this scope. The
>   cursor can be referenced by local
>   cursor variables in the batch, stored
>   procedure, or trigger, or a stored
>   procedure OUTPUT parameter. An OUTPUT
>   parameter is used to pass the local
>   cursor back to the calling batch,
>   stored procedure, or trigger, which
>   can assign the parameter to a cursor
>   variable to reference the cursor after
>   the stored procedure terminates. The
>   cursor is implicitly deallocated when
>   the batch, stored procedure, or
>   trigger terminates, unless the cursor
>   was passed back in an OUTPUT
>   parameter. If it is passed back in an
>   OUTPUT parameter, the cursor is
>   deallocated when the last variable
>   referencing it is deallocated or goes
>   out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can restrict the scope of a cursor to the stored procedure with

DECLARE  CURSOR LOCAL

Answer (score 2):

Are the cursors `local` cursors or `global` cursors?...Make them `local` or just change the name of one of the cursors and be done with it

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically **need** a global cursor, use a local cursor.

If your cursor declaration does not include the keyword LOCAL or GLOBAL, then SQL Server will use its default server configuration. You can determine the default configuration by using this query:

```
SELECT is_local_cursor_default FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  For confirmation, see this Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

By default, if the LOCAL / GLOBAL switch isn't filled out when declaring the cursor, it will be implicitly set to LOCAL. I do however suggest that LOCAL be defined for other peoples clarity when reading your code.

Please refer to the following article note:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

If you are writing two cursors within the same scope (same stored procedure), simply name them different names.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The default setting (LOCAL / GLOBAL) is controlled by the is_local_cursor_default setting in sys.databases.  See this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16